# PyInstaller installed 'successfully' using pip but pyinstaller.py is nowhere to be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyinstaller

I'm running Python 3.5.3 on Windows and I attempted to install Pyinstaller with pip. It seemed to work- no errors or anything, very simple as pip always is.

I tried `import -m pyinstaller` but it said the module didn't exist, so I checked the installation folder as the documentation says [you should be able to use pyinstaller.py directly from the install location.](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/installation.html)

[image: Here] Here is a picture of that location, pyinstaller.py isn't there! It's not in any sub-folders or other folders either. I think I'm just missing something obvious but after an hour of uninstalling and reinstalling everything I'd appreciate if someone would help me out. Thanks!

Comment: `import -m pyinstaller` makes no sense. Also have you tried running `pyinstaller` directly?

Answer (score 2):

Why import? you should run pyinstaller directly on your console:

```
pyinstaller --onedir your_app_main.py
```

or

```
pyinstaller --onefile your_app_main.py
```

check this PyInstaller Manual:
https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/